# Adding styles to after and before pseudo elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a button and it has these styles when user clicks on it:

```
.answer-buttons:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
}

.answer-buttons:active::before {
  border-top-width: 10px;
  border-bottom-width: 10px;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  top: -10px;
  border-left-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.answer-buttons:active::after {
  border-top-width: 10px;
  border-bottom-width: 10px;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  top: -10px;
  border-right-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

As you see, the `active` is affecting the button and its `after` and `before` pseudo elements right?

Now I want to activate the button when user presses a key on his keyboard:

```
 window.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);

    function keyPress(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 37) {
           // code to activate the button shape
           window.removeEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
        }  
    }
```

So I need a solution to make the above styles on the button and its `after` and `before` pseudo elements via JavaScript.

If there was only the element, we could do this simply by adding a new class but with `after` and `before` I can't find a proper solution to make this work?

Comment: Your class solution would work actually, simply add a class on keydown and remove it on keyup, then in your css you could do somethnig like .answer-buttons.my-new-class::before

Comment: simply do `yourButton.focus()`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can amend the CSS to also use an `.active` class as well as the `:active` state. Then you can simply add/remove the class when the necessary key is pressed.

```js
let buttons =  document.querySelectorAll('.answer-buttons');
window.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
window.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp);

function keyPress(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) // left cursor
   buttons.forEach(el => el.classList.add('active'));
}

function keyUp(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) // left cursor
    buttons.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
}
```

```css
.answer-buttons:active,
.answer-buttons.active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
}

.answer-buttons:active::before,
.answer-buttons.active::before {
  border-top-width: 10px;
  border-bottom-width: 10px;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  top: -10px;
  border-left-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.answer-buttons:active::after,
.answer-buttons.active::after {
  border-top-width: 10px;
  border-bottom-width: 10px;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  top: -10px;
  border-right-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<button class="answer-buttons">Foo</button>
```